# Is SQL Server's Telemetry CEIP "spyware"?

Tags: terminology

SQL Server has a process called Telemetry that is,

- opt-out
- closed-source
- tracks the user
- tracks usage patterns
- bundled with "desirable" software

It's marketed as "Customer Experience Improvement Program", and previously "Service Quality Monitoring", and even before that "Software Quality Metrics". Does this qualify it as "spyware"?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 4):

No.

[Meriam Webster defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spyware) spyware as:

```
software that is installed in a computer without the user's knowledge and transmits
information about the user's computer activities over the Internet
```

Since the SQL Server installer asks the user if they want to turn it off, the user has knowledge that it was installed.  Therefore it is not spyware.

Comment: It doesn't ask. You have to manually turn it off.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - Except you installed `MS SQL Server` by choice.

Comment: If I install Limewire by choice and it installs a Telemetry Browser Plugin by default that I can opt-out of that sends unspecified data to a centralized location, would it also not be spyware because Limewire was installed by choice?

Comment: I think this answer could be expanded to include the difference between software that hides the fact that it tracks it's users, and software that provides the ability to turn it off (even if it is on by default).

Comment: @EvanCarroll - That is a matter of opinion, it’s clear, you believe that’s the case.  I don’t believe that’s the case.  Spyware is software that is installed without your knowledge, silently, without any user intervention.  If you install Limeware, then you have accepted that Alienware, comes with an default add-on.  Similar to how operating systems, come with basic utilities, services, and applications already installed.